# iPhone:App crashes while fetching the character from array to unichar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have an array with two blank characters as follows:

```
shuffleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"H",@"E",@"",@"",@"O", nil];
```

Now I want to assign the values of array to unichar for further coding as follows:

```
for(int i=0; i<[shuffleArray count]; i++)
{
       NSString *temp = [shuffleArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"string:%@",temp);
        unichar c = [temp characterAtIndex:0];
}
```

it prints "H" and "E" fine but when it found blank characters i.e. @"" .

It gets crash at  the point

```
unichar c = [temp characterAtIndex:0];
```

How can I solve this problem.

Any help will be appriciable.

Thanx in advance..

Comment: could it be because there is no characterAtIndex 0 on an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out it works

```
  for( NSString *temp in shuffleArray )
  {
    NSLog(@"string:%@",temp);
    if (temp.length) {
      unichar c = [temp characterAtIndex:0];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

from characterAtIndex: reference:

> **Discussion**
>
> Raises an NSRangeException if index lies beyond the end of
>   the receiver.

So you need to check if string is not empty before trying to access its character

```
NSString *temp = [shuffleArray objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"string:%@",temp);
unichar c = someInitialValue; // to indicate later that the string was empty may be equal 0 ?
if ([temp length] > 0) [temp characterAtIndex:0];
```

Your loop condition is also wrong as on the last iteration (when i is equal to [shuffleArray count]) You'll get the same NSRangeException exception

Answer (score 1):

i see 2 mistake in this code :

```
NSMutableArray *shuffleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"H",@"E",@"",@"",@"O", nil];

for(int i=0; i < [shuffleArray count]; i++) // < and not <=
{
    NSString *temp = [shuffleArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"string:%@",temp);
    if ([temp length] > 0)
    {
        unichar c = [temp characterAtIndex:0]; // Check if you can acces to the element before
        NSLog(@"%c", c);
    }
}
```